# How to detect what item is on the screen in react-native FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I want to detect what item is showing on the screen in `FlatList` that render an aditional view in that item after 2 seconds of focus. (like comment filed in instagram)

In the Other word, I want to render an aditional view to `PostItem` after 2 seconds that it's showing on the screen. I try to add `setTimeout` in `useEfect` to make that component visible. But the `PostItem` in `FlatList` and all the list render concurrently and after 2 seconds all PostItems have this component.

Is there any solution for this?
If the solution is to use `onViewableItemsChanged​` prop in `FlatList`, how to implemet that with this prop?

here is my FlatList component:

```
const _renderItem: ListRenderItem<Post> = ({item}) => {
  return <PostItem {...item} />;
};

<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
  renderItem={_renderItem}
  onEndReached={_onEndReached}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of the element and find it in your data array using

```
  const onItemIndexChange = useCallback(setHourIndex, []);

  const ITEM_HEIGHT = height_of_one_item_rendered

      onMomentumScrollEnd={(ev) => {
          const newIndex = Math.round(ev.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y / ITEM_HEIGHT);
          if (onItemIndexChangeHour) {
            onItemIndexChange(newIndex + 1);
          }
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onViewableItemsChanged` Flatlist property https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onviewableitemschanged

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your renderItem with visibility sensor component

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svanboxel/visibility-sensor-react-native

Comment: i am not able to install this using npm, its saying npm ERR! No versions available for visibility-sensor-react-native, any alternative for this one ?